# how to keep ngrx DRY?

Tags: angular, ngrx

DRY Don't repeat yourself

I've got two pieces of state.

One deal with cars and one with planes.

All the actions are copy and paste and change the action names.

All the effects are copy and paste and change the effect names and request URLs.

All the reducers are essentially copy and paste.

Is there any way to avoid this duplication in ngrx?

Thx

Comment: Do you mean `ngrx`? Or `ng-redux`?

Comment: ngrx is what I mean

Comment: Is `ngrx-store` a more appropriate tag? It seems like this question refers to that specific part of `ngrx`

Comment: ngrx is a store solution

Comment: "NgRx provides a set of reactive libraries for Angular" is the tag, maybe this should be updated? Also, https://github.com/ngrx?tab=repositories states that ngrx is "Reactive Extensions for Angular"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course there is, you could perfectly fine apply generics to states and effects. Actions are identified in your store by their type, so make sure you include that, and you're good to go.

The sad result is that when using your actions, you need to add logic since

```
store.dispatch(new Load('car'));
```

Frankly is less nice and less typesafe then

```
store.dispatch(new LoadCar());
```

For effects, yes you could create a single effect which accepts multiple types:

```
$loadCar = this.actions.pipe(
   ofType([VehicleActions.loadCar, VehicleActions.loadTruck]),
   this.applyLoadLogic
)

$loadTruck = this.actions.pipe(
   ofType(VehicleActions.loadTrailer),
   obs => this.applyLoadLogic(obs, false)
)

applyLoadLogic(in: Observable<Action>, canDrive: boolean = true): Observable<Action> {
   return in.pipe(
      map(action => this.doMagic(action.payload, canDrive))
   );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First keep in mind that actions/reducers are not boilerplate. While it may feel like it is, it is not because your domain is different, eg an employee is not a order.

That said there is [@ngrx/entity](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/tree/master/docs/entity) to manage your collections.

And there is also [ngrx-data](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-ngrx-data) that creates everything you said (actions, reducers, effects and services).

Comment: ¿ngrx-data over  ngrx-schematics?

Answer (score 1):

No , this is ngrx(redux) famous "boilerplate"  but watch the author of ngrx giving some good hints about
Reducing the Boilerplate with NgRx - Brandon Roberts & Mike Ryan 

 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t3jx0EC-Y3c

Comment: quote " What is ngrx?
Redux state managers have been very well received and have inspired the creation of ngrx, a set of modules that implement the same way of managing state as well as some of the middleware and tools in the Redux ecosystem. ngrx was created to be used specifically with Angular and RxJS, as it leans heavily on the observable paradigm." I think with reactive extension you mean Rxjs